# Google Chrome freeze on wake up touch screen, not reponse until touch outside the web or mouse move/click o keyboard key press

Tags: google-chrome, touch, microsoft-edge, chromium

I have been fatal for a few days with this incident. After the latest Chrome updates I am left with a headache.

We have ASUS v161 touch screens (although it happens to us in more models), and we open the chrome in kiosk mode. The power configuration is high performance and we only turn off the screen after 15 minutes (no sleep). We have also tried disabling anything that turns off the hard drive or usb without success.

We have tried to activate all the touch flags, we have deactivated the hardware acceleration, etc ... But it is happening with the last 3 updates.

Chrome version: 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) (64 bits)

Windows version:
Windows 10 Pro Edition
Version 20H2
Installed on 09/25/2020
Operating system version 19042.746
Windows Experience Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

The issue is that when you return from the off screen, by touching with your finger, the screen turns on but the web content that chrome shows does not respond.

If we do not open it in kiosk mode, it does not respond until we touch anywhere in Windows or in the chrome address bar, then it begins to respond. But the web does not respond by itself if we do not touch outside of it. The web is frozen, te text cursor are freeze. (This also happens with Edge) It does not happen with Firefox.

If you hit it with the mouse, no problem, all return to be responsive

Video attachment: https://youtu.be/BH2abO6AXaM

In the video it is clear how the system activates the screen with touch, but chrome is frozen, the cursor does not move, it does not respond to any link, there is a moment where the screen goes blank, and at the end you see how it responds when I touchthe address bar. This happens right away if you hit the address bar or any other windows/desktop of Windows.

When Chome wake up all touch response are ok and the cursor blink again. If like's Chrome still sleeping until other event different than touch success.

Thanks a lot

Jorge

Comment: Can you please inform us which version of the Edge browser causing this issue? It can be possible that Chromium-based browsers checking for proxy settings indefinitely causing this issue. Just for testing purposes on Win 10, can you please go to `Settings-> Network & Internet-> Proxy` and turn off the **Automatically Detect Settings** option. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/sjCi5zU) If you are using the proxy then manually try to configure it. After that try to check for the issue in the MS Edge and Google Chrome browser to see whether the issue gets fixed.

Comment: The last update of Edge, i have Windows version: Windows 10 Pro Edition Version 20H2 Installed on 09/25/2020 Operating system version 19042.746 Windows Experience Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

I already have disabled the proxy option. I already opened a chromium issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1175109

Tomorrow i will send you the exact version

Comment: I suggest you press the `ALT + SHIFT + I` key in the Edge browser window and try to provide feedback about this issue to Microsoft. Thanks for your understaning.

Comment: Versión 88.0.705.63 (Compilación oficial) (64 bits)

Comment: I i view that the problem are in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: And I view that the problem are in text are if I have the touch on screen keyboard disabled.

Comment: We have the same problem, but in our case we don't turn off screen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389912/chrome-in-kiosk-mode-with-touch-screen

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too for a few months, but it went away with Chrome v91. Upgrade to the latest version of Chrome if you're still on a lower version.

Comment: Seems like a comment